# python thread error

Tags: python, multithreading

```
obj = functioning()

from threading import Thread
Thread(target=obj.runCron(cronDetails)).start()
print "new thread started..."
```

I am runnning this, this should run as new thread for runCron function and should print new thread started. but this is not printing new thread started and not creating new thread

Comment: what is it doing? What happens instead? Do you get an error? Please paste the full error traceback then.

Comment: If you are getting any kind of exception, then please post the error messages - or at least those, which seem to be relevant to you - too.

Answer (score 2):

You question is missing some details, e.g. what error message you are getting, etc. – below is a working example mimicked after your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

class Obj(object):
    def runCron(self, cronDetails):
        time.sleep(1)
        print cronDetails

obj = Obj()
cronDetails = "I'm here."

from threading import Thread

# Note, that the `target` is a function object
# (or a callable in general), we don't actually call it yet!
t = Thread(target=obj.runCron, args=(cronDetails, ))
t.start()
print "New thread started (should be here in a second) ..."
```

It prints:

```
New thread started (should be here in a second) ...
I'm here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to call `obj.runCron(cronDetails)` inside the thread. But what that code does is to call `obj.runCron(cronDetails)` first, and then **pass the result of that** to the `Thread` class.

If that's the case, the code below should fix it:

```
obj = functioning()

from threading import Thread
Thread(target=obj.runCron, args=(cronDetails,)).start()
print "new thread started..."
```

Note that I'm not calling `obj.runCron` myself anymore, but passing that method with the arguments separately to `threading.Thread` so it can be called **inside the thread** with the correct arguments.

If that doesn't do what you want, please provide more info as I asked in the comment.